# Failing while passing dataframe column seperated by comma into a API

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have to pass  locations to API to retrieve values.

**Working Code**

```
 dfs = []
locations = ['ZRH','SIN']
for loc in locations:
    response = requests.get(f'https://risk.dev.tyche.eu-central-1.aws.int.kn/il/risk/location/{loc}', headers=headers, verify=False)
    if 'items' in data:
        df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'items', 'totalItems')     
        df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df.pop('relatedEntities')], keys=df.index).add_prefix('relatedEntities.')
        df3 = df.join((df1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
        dfs.append(df3)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

**Failing Code ( while passing as parameter)**

When I try to pass location as parameter which is created another dataframe column it fails.

```
Unique_Location = data['LOCATION'].unique()
Unique_Location = pd.DataFrame( list(zip(Unique_Location)), columns =['Unique_Location'])
t= ','.join(map(repr,Unique_Location['Unique_Location'] ))

locations = [t]
    for loc in locations:
        response = requests.get(f'https://risk.dev.logindex.com/il/risk/location/{loc}', headers=headers)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'items', 'totalItems')
```

What is  wrong in my code?

Error

```
`c:\users\ashok.eapen\pycharmprojects\rs-components\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _pull_records(js, spec)
    246         if has non iterable value.
    247         """
--> 248         result = _pull_field(js, spec)
    249 
    250         # GH 31507 GH 30145, GH 26284 if result is not list, raise TypeError if not

c:\users\ashok.eapen\pycharmprojects\rs-components\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _pull_field(js, spec)
    237                 result = result[field]
    238         else:
--> 239             result = result[spec]
    240         return result
    241 

KeyError: 'items'
```

`

Comment: What is `Unique_Location.head()` ? Maybe need  instead `for loc in locations` use `for loc in Unique_Location['Unique_Location']` or better `for loc in data['LOCATION'].unique()`

Comment: `Unique_Location
0 NZAKL
1 NZ23-USBCH
2 DEBAD
3 AEJEA
4 ARBUE` . Its a column values inside a dataframe

Comment: @jezrael, its failing

Comment: hmmm, what is error?

Comment: @jezrael, error pasted in the question as its too long

Comment: OK, I guess some values not exist in API so it failed. So is possible test `locations = ['some not exist code','CODENOTEXIST']` for prove it?

Comment: @jezrael, tested it . Your assumption is true. Is there a way In which we can skip a value which if doesnt exist go to next value.

Comment: @jezrael, its `<Response [200]>`

Comment: sorry, I think what is `print (response.text)` for not exist values?

Comment: @jezrael, `{"timestamp":1620021245651,"path":"/il/risk/location/ZRHsdsd","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"","requestId":"2db523eb-114862"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231869/discussion-between-aeapen-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if `items` exist in json like:

```
dfs = []
locations = ['NZAKL', 'NZ23-USBCH', 'DEBAD', 'ARBUE', 'AR02_GSTI', 'AEJEA', 'UYMVD', 'UY03', 'AE01_GSTI', 'TH02_GSTI', 'JO01_GSTI', 'ITSIM', 'GB75_GSTI', 'DEAMA', 'DE273_GSTI', 'ITPRO', 'AT07_GSTI', 'FR05', 'FRHAU', 'FR01_GSTI', 'FRHER', 'ES70X-FRLBM', 'THNEO']
for loc in locations:
    response = requests.get(f'https://risk.dev.logindex.com/il/risk/location/{loc}', headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    if 'items' in data:
        if len(data['items']) > 0:
            df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'items', 'totalItems') 
            
            #NaN in column, so failed - replace NaN to empty list
            f = lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else []
            df['raw.identifiers'] = df['raw.identifiers'].apply(f)
            df['raw.relationships'] = df['raw.relationships'].apply(f)
            df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df.pop('raw.identifiers')], keys=df.index).add_prefix('raw.identifiers.')
            df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df.pop('raw.relationships')], keys=df.index).add_prefix('raw.relationships.')
            
            df3 = df.join(df1.join(df2).reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
            dfs.append(df3)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I get an error "ValueError: No objects to concatenate". I have pasted code in our chat

Comment: @aeapen - So it means no data match? For some reason `data['LOCATION'].unique()` not exist?

Comment: @aeapen - So `if 'items' in data` return always `False` ?

Comment: I tested like this `locations = ['ZRH','SIN','NOVALUE]'`. Here `reponse.text ` value is there both ZRH and SIN  still it fails.

Comment: I have pasted the working code in our chat, but it fails when I have non -existant value . Can you have look

Comment: @aeapen - testing now

Comment: @aeapen - for me working well, added code to answer.

Comment: its works for me as well. But I when I location value from  dataframe column with all non-existant values its fails

Comment: ,`KeyError: 'raw.identifiers'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-bbcd0fa295ab> in <module>
     17         df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'items', 'totalItems')
     18 
---> 19         df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df.pop('raw.identifiers')], keys=df.index).add_prefix('raw.identifiers.')
   
     21 ` . This is the error

Comment: @aeapen - hmmm, it means some json is different for some code, here not exist `raw.identifiers`. Is possible identify what code failed?

Comment: It works absoutely fine when I dont use dataframe to pass value.Can you try to create a datafrme and pass values to location.`locations = Unique_Location['Unique_Location'].unique()
for loc in locations:`

Comment: @aeapen - So it is not problem with codes? `locations = Unique_Location['Unique_Location'].unique().tolist()` create list with codes. So I guess for some reason thid codes returned different json data like codes `'SIN','ZRH'`

Comment: @aeapen - I try with `locations = ['NZAKL','NZ23-USBCH', 'NOVALUE','DEBAD']` and working nice

Comment: This is what I get from ` response .text` as response
`'{"items":[],"totalItems":0,"errors":[]}'`

Comment: @aeapen - Can you check edit? `if len(data['items']) > 0:` ?

Comment: works perfectly . Issue occurs only when I read locations from dataframe .This works` locations = ['NZAKL','NZ23-USBCH', 'NOVALUE','DEBAD']` and `locations = Unique_Location['Unique_Location'].unique().tolist()` is not working

Comment: @aeapen - `locations = Unique_Location['Unique_Location'].unique().tolist()` so there is difference with `locations = ['NZAKL','NZ23-USBCH', 'NOVALUE','DEBAD']` ?

Comment: yup the dataframe column has more locations

Comment: @aeapen so `NZ23-USBCH` is necessary split to 2 codes like `NZ2, USBCH`?

Comment: that's. not needed, each row in  data frame column is unique value .

Comment: if value is `NZ23-USBCH` then take value as such

Comment: @aeapen - hmmm, is possible post `locations  = Unique_Location['Unique_Location'].unique().tolist()` and `print(locations)` to question?

Comment: here it is `['NZAKL', 'NZ23-USBCH', 'DEBAD', 'ARBUE', 'AR02_GSTI', 'AEJEA', 'UYMVD', 'UY03', 'AE01_GSTI', 'TH02_GSTI', 'JO01_GSTI', 'ITSIM', 'GB75_GSTI', 'DEAMA', 'DE273_GSTI', 'ITPRO', 'AT07_GSTI', 'FR05', 'FRHAU', 'FR01_GSTI', 'FRHER', 'ES70X-FRLBM', 'THNEO']`

Comment: @aeapen - And for this values solution not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231917/discussion-between-aeapen-and-jezrael).

Comment: @aeapen - I fond problem, there is NaN in `raw.relationships`. Working on solution.

Comment: @, Can you try with this https://risk.dev.tyche.eu-central-1.aws.int.kn/il/risk/location/ API. Key is same

Comment: @aeapen - I got `ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='risk.dev.tyche.eu-central-1.aws.int.kn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /il/risk/location/NZAKL (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000CDBA5B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))`

Comment: @aeapen - tested `requests.get(f'https://risk.dev.logindex.com/il/risk/location/{loc}', headers=headers)`

Comment: Can you try now. I not gettting HTTPS connection error now

Comment: the related entities values getting properly

Comment: for this risk.dev.tyche.eu-central-1.aws.int.kn/il/risk/location  It is tagging the values correctly